# android unit test + robolectric 3.0 + java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: android, robolectric

Error:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
> method "com.example.demo.utils.R.init(Landroid/content/Context;)V" the
> class loader (instance of
> org/robolectric/internal/bytecode/InstrumentingClassLoader) of the
> current class, com/example/test/FirstTest, and the class loader
> (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's
> defining class, com/example/demo/utils/R, have different Class objects
> for the type android/content/Context used in the signature

test code:

```java
    @runwith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
    @config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 21,application = TestApplication.class)
    public class FirstTest{
            @test
            public void testCase01(){
                 MainActivity mainActivity =  Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
                ....
           }
        }
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.0'
...
}
```

src/test/java/.../TestApplication:

```java
    public class TestApplication extends Application {
    }
```

com/example/demo/MainActivity:

```java
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        com.example.demo.utils.R.init(getApplicationContext());
        ...
        }
    }
```

com/example/demo/utils/R:

```java
    public final class R {
        public static Resources resources;
        private static String packageName;
        public static void init(Context paramContext) {
           resources = paramContext.getResources();
           packageName = paramContext.getPackageName();
        }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason why tests run fail is using a class named `com.example.demo.utils.R`, which has a conflict with an `R` class 
 autogenerated by the Android System. If you rename `R` to another name, like `Ra`, it works.